# Excel Cell Color by AutoCAD color in contents

Tags: excel, vba, colors, autocad

Output I'm hoping for is similar to this page: http://sub-atomic.com/~moses/acadcolors.html, but in Excel.

What we're trying to do is to tie AutoCAD colors to a cell. I want to be able to enter a color number in the cell (say color 10, which is red), and have the cell change to that color. I don't know how to do this without doing a macro. I assume it's going to be VBA of some type.

I have the RGB equivalents from the site above - I assume I can pull some type of a lookup.

I realize this can be done with a particularly nasty bit of conditional formatting, but I'd really prefer something a little more streamlined.

Help?

**EDIT:** UGP provided some really good code which did exactly what I needed. This is the final code I wound up using (adjusted for my sheet naming and with a bit of additional functionality).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim KeyCells As Range
  Set KeyCells = Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1000, 6))

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
    Is Nothing Then

    CellChanged = Target.Address 'Cell that changed
    If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Value) Then
      If Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Value = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Font.Color = vbBlack
      Else
        Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Interior.Color = 
        Color(Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Value)
        Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Font.Color = 
        textColor(Worksheets("Master").Range(CellChanged).Value)
      End If
    End If

  End If
End Sub

Function Color(ByRef ID As Integer) As Long
  Dim R, G, B As Integer
  For i = 3 To 257
    If ID = Worksheets("Colors").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
      R = Worksheets("Colors").Cells(i, 2).Value
      G = Worksheets("Colors").Cells(i, 3).Value
      B = Worksheets("Colors").Cells(i, 4).Value
      Color = RGB(R, G, B)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function

Function textColor(ByRef ID As Integer) As Long
  If ID <= 9 Then
    textColor = vbBlack
  Else
    If ID Mod 10 >= 4 Then
      textColor = vbWhite
    Else
      textColor = vbBlack
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in Sheet1  by opening the editor with alt+f11:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1000, 1000))

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

       CellChanged = Target.Address 'Cell that changed
       If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CellChanged).Value) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CellChanged).Interior.Color = Color(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CellChanged).Value)
       End If
    End If
End Sub

Function Color(ByRef ID As Integer) As Long
Dim R, G, B As Integer
    For i = 2 To 256
        If ID = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value Then
            R = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Value
            G = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 6).Value
            B = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value
            Color = RGB(R, G, B)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It'll check for user input from Cell(1,1) to Cell(1000,1000) then it grabs the Color from Sheet2 where i put the autocad table you linked like this (copy and paste the table):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was extremely helpful. I added in a few sections to deal with the text color as well, but this worked exactly as intended. There was also a slight bug with the empty cell - a simply if/then prevented it from turning black.

Comment: Could you suggest an edit, so that the changes are visible for everyone. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably a good call. What's the accepted method of doing that on this site?

Comment: Under my post should be a button "Suggest edit" then replace my code with yours otherwise just post a comment with your code and i will edit my post

Comment: the edit queue seems to be full, and it's too long to put in a comment. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: you can post it as an answer to your own question

Comment: that probably would have been better. Darnit. Oh well. Thanks!